# SSO setup with shibboleth

Tags: single-sign-on, shibboleth

I am new to this subject and was tasked with setting up an SSO environment
using shibboleth IDP. I downloaded the IDP software from the shibboleth website and tweaked the settings according to a few online guides. In the end I want to connect the IDP to a service now instance to work as the SP. I don't know why but the connection doesn't happen. Is there anything I'm missing that I should have for just a skeleton of the system to work? I skipped anything involving federation registration and encryption as this is not relevant for the time being. I don't know a lot about SSO systems and I don;t know if I just have a few settings wrong in the IDP or if I completely mis-understood how SSO's work.

Comment: More description would be helpful. Things like, what SP are you using what are the shibboleth files etc.

Comment: the SP is a service now instance the shibboleth files are the standard IDP download for windows